# How to prevent Ant Design Table re-render after row selection?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, ant-design-pro

I have AntD table on my page with big data and after selecting one row, it re-renders the entire table. How can I re-render only the selected row, instead of re-rendering all rows?

Comment: Oh god, I'm just coming across this and I can't find anything online. I have custom cells and everything but the entire table reloads on selecting a row and it's so annoying